# Can I get a scrollable tooltip in draw2d?

Tags: eclipse, tooltip, draw2d

I want to make the tooltip scrollable in draw2D, just like in Eclipse when you call out the Content Assist window. Can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I have never tried it, but I see no reason why using a `org.eclipse.draw2d.ScrollPane` in your tooltip shouldn't work. You will probably have to put the `ScrollPane` into another figure to restrict its size. Otherwise I suspect the `ScrollPane` (and with it the whole tooltip) would just have the preferred size of its content -> no scrolling.